# Autoloading from namespace inside a custom folder in app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

We're currently developing a custom cms engine for ROR 3.2. In this process several class types originated that we want to be first class citizens in our rails application, meaning they should reside under the app folder of the application and it's plugins.

Currently we're having the following types:

- DataSource
- DataType
- View

I created multible directories under the app folder to hold these:

- app/data_source
- app/data_type
- app/view

More types will follow and I'm a little worried with polluting the app folder with so many directories. Thus i want to move them into a subdirectory/module that holds all Types defined by the cms.

All classes should be inside a **MyCms** namespace and the directory layout should look like this:

- app/my_cms/data_source
- app/my_cms/data_type
- app/my_cms/view

But now I'm having trouble with autoloading because rails default autoloading would excpect the paths to be like this:

- app/data_source/my_cms
- app/data_type/my_cms
- app/view/my_cms

But this way I would not have grouped all object types in one directory.

What I want is somewhat similar to view grouping of isolated engines. In [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for example, all views are grouped in the views/devise subdirectory.

Any idea how this could be achieved without to much custom implementation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You would have to add app/my_cms to your autoload path within config/application.rb:

```
config.autoload_paths << "#{config.root}/app/my_cms"
```

provided that your classes are defined without a namespace like this:

```
class DataSource
  ...
end
```

If you namespace them like this in app/my_cms/data_source.rb:

```
class MyCms::DataSource
  ...
end
```

you might add the app folder to the load path:

```
config.autoload_paths << "#{config.root}/app"
```

Alternatively, you can do it manually but you lose the reloading for those classes in Rails development:

in app/my_cms.rb (and with autoloading for app in place):

```
module MyCms
  autoload :AnotherDataSource, 'my_cms/data_source/one_data_source'
  autoload :AnotherDataSource, 'my_cms/data_source/another_data_source'

  ...
end
```

Comment: And if I wanted them bo be namespaced? A namespace would bring the advantage that everything from the cms would be encapsulated. Also autocompletion in IDE's would be greatly enhanced because i could type in MyCms::, execute the autocomplete function and see all important classes.

Comment: Thanxs. Thats already pretty nice, but whats still missing are the subdirectories. Meaning the data sources are not beneath the data_source folder...

Comment: Hmm I don't understand, you would name your classes like this `class MyCms::DataSource::A`, `class MyCms::DataSource::B`, etc. No?

Comment: Thats the problem... no. I would like it to be named MyCms::OneDataSource and MyCms::AnotherDataSource. The other way of your last comment would be easy ;)

Comment: I added another way to the answer.

Comment: Is this still expected to work in Rails 4? When I do `app/my_cms/data_source` and `config.autoload_paths << "#{config.root}/app"` Rails still doesn't seem to see `MyCms::DataSource`?

Comment: Yeah, I just tested it and it works fine with rails 4. What does the error message say excatly?